# How to update Avalonia UI ComboBox when ObservableCollection was updated

Tags: c#, mvvm, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a `C# Avalonia` [project](https://github.com/Wissance/Zerial) to communicate any Serial (`RS232`) devices, currently i am at the beginning of developing this app. I decided to use `Avalonia` to build cross-platform application (`Windows`, `Linux`). However i faced an issue when component (`ComboBox`) source `IList` / `IObservableCollection` is updated i can't update combobox content.

My Ports list looks like:

```
    <ComboBox Name="PortsListSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ports, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPortNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                   DropDownOpened="OnPortNumberListOpened"
                                                   Classes="ConnOptCombo" Margin="5 0 0 0" Width="100"/>
```

On dropdown is opened i handle event in `MainWindow`:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _context = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = _context;
    }

    private void OnPortNumberListOpened(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.ReEnumeratePorts();
    }
        
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _context;
}
```

In the event handler i call `ReEnumeratePorts` fucntion to check what ports we have in the system. In the my `MainWindowViewModel` i was trying to use dfferent approaches but still can't get it work:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SerialOptions = new SerialDefaultsModel();
        _ports = new ObservableCollection<string (Rs232PortsEnumerator.GetAvailablePorts()?.ToList() ?? new List<string>());
        SelectedPortNumber = Ports.Any() ? Ports.First() : null;
    }

    // 
    public void ReEnumeratePorts()
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanging("Ports");
        Ports = new ObservableCollection<string>(Rs232PortsEnumerator.GetAvailablePorts());
        SelectedPortNumber = Ports.Any() ? Ports.First() : null; 
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Ports");
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPortNumber");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Ports
    {
        get { return _ports; }
        set
        {

            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _ports, value);
        }
    }
    // ... other methods && props

    private ObservableCollection<string> _ports;
}
```

My Question is: How to enforce ComboBox to update it content by updating Binded `ItemsSource` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to do this but not via `ObservableCollection`, `AvaloniaList` or other "observable collection" (tutorials aren't working) instead of this i just used old well known `Windows Forms` `Event Handling`

1. I replaced `ObservableCollection` with classic `IList`:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _ports = new List<string (Rs232PortsEnumerator.GetAvailablePorts().ToList());
        SelectedPortNumber = Ports.Any() ? Ports.First() : null;
        // other initialize
    }

    // ReEnumeratePorts returns List!
    public IList<string> ReEnumeratePorts()
    {
        Ports.Clear();
        IList<string> newPorts = Rs232PortsEnumerator.GetAvailablePorts();
        Ports = newPorts;
        return newPorts;
    }

    // other methods ...
    
    // Ports property
    public IList<string> Ports
    {
        get { return _ports; }
        set
        {
            _ports = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // other props ...
    private IList<string> _ports;
}
```

2. After some practical survey i discovered that `PointerEntered` is a most suitable event to nadle, therefore my `axaml` part shown below:

```
<ComboBox Name="PortsListSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ports, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPortNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      PointerEntered="OnPortsPointerControlMouseOver" Classes="ConnOptCombo" Margin="5 0 0 0" Width="100"/>
```

3. And i added following `OnPortsPointerControlMouseOver` method to my window code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _context = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = _context;
    }
        
    private void OnPortsPointerControlMouseOver(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<string> ports = _context.ReEnumeratePorts();
        PortsListSelect.ItemsSource = ports as IEnumerable;
        PortsListSelect.SelectedItem = ports.Any() ? ports [0]: null;
    }
        
    private readonly MainWindowViewModel _context;
}
```

Unfortunately i was unable to do the same via `MVVM` with an observables and a property change event raise but my solution is working, a little bit late i'll edit answer and post a link to video with demo of how all this works.

Full example could be found in [github repo](https://github.com/Wissance/Zerial).

P.S. @Tarazed, thanks for attempts to help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't utilizing the `ObservableCollection` correctly.  The point of an observable collection is to allow it to notify when it's contents change, but you are replacing it with an entirely new collection every time you re-enumerate by changing the holding property itself.  Consider clearing the list and re-adding.  Using this approach I recommend removing the setter on your `Ports` property, make it read-only unless you have a good reason to change it.

Below is a brute force approach, with some creativity you could filter just the ones that have changed, I'll leave that to you.

```cs
public void ReEnumeratePorts()
{
    Ports.Clear();
    var newPorts = Rs232PortsEnumerator.GetAvailablePorts();
    foreach (string port in newPorts)
    {
        Ports.Add(port);
    }
    // Set selected item, no need to raise property changed events here.
}
```

Truthfully, I'm not seeing why the original method didn't work at a glacne. It should have raised INotifyPropertyChanged and updated anyway.  But it's not an efficient design creating a new object every time and throwing stuff off to the garbage collector needlessly, so I would remove that design anyway.

Comment: thanks for you reply, unfortunately, i can't get it work with you approach. Don't even understand what is wrong (i was not commited to repo because still no result).

Comment: @MichaelUshakov I just noticed you are renumerating every time the drop down opens.  That's going to clear the list as soon as it opens, that's not a good time to do it.  Are you expecting hardware to change that often?

Comment: Actually i could use WMI to query periodically what COM devices i have in a system, but i discovered that it is quite reasonable to re-enumerate on clicking dropdown (it is not often, but new hardware could be attached in any time, therefore it is neccessarry to check new hardware)

Comment: @MichaelUshakov Try using my the mouse down event, not sure if that will work, but I feel like refreshing the list after the drop down is open is too late.  If that doesn't work, try to create an minimal reproduceable example.

Comment: I've tried different exception unfortunately can't get it work, maybe something wrong with my DataContext of app or window configuration/

Comment: @MichaelUshakov I'm sorry but without an MRE I am unable to help any further. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ Tarazed, see my question post, project word is a link to github repo